# Custom alignment of text in itemized environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize

I want to describe the variables involved in an equation in an itemized environment such that every item begins with the variable name and subsequently comes the description for it. I'd like to have all the descriptions left aligned.

Here is a MWE that of course does not produce what I am looking for.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
$E[g(x)] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(x) \, g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$.
%
where,
%
\begin{itemize}
    \item $x$      \quad is a continuous random variable.
    \item $f_X(x)$ \quad is the PDF of $x$.
    \item $g(x)$   \quad is a function of $x$.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `usepackage{enumitem}` and `\begin{itemize}[align=left]` and then `\item[$x$]{is a continuous random variable.}`?

Comment: @Adam, That doesn't seem to work right for me. Did you try and it worked?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I think I understand what you want now. Do you still want the bullet points to be there?

Comment: No worries. Yes, I do want the bullets as well =)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

What about this

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$E[g(x)] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(x) \, g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$.
%
where,
%
\begin{itemize}
    \item{\makebox[2cm]{$x$\hfill} is a continuous random variable.}
    \item{\makebox[2cm]{$f_X(x)$\hfill} is the PDF of $x$.}
    \item{\makebox[2cm]{$g(x)$\hfill} is a function of $x$.}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

You can avoid using `\hfill` for each item if you specify the second optional argument of `\makebox` to be the letter `l` (for left):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$E[g(x)] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(x) \, g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$.
%
where,
%
\begin{itemize}
    \item{\makebox[2cm][l]{$x$} is a continuous random variable.}
    \item{\makebox[2cm][l]{$f_X(x)$} is the PDF of $x$.}
    \item{\makebox[2cm][l]{$g(x)$} is a function of $x$.}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this `\makebox` is an excellent solution as it will work for lists that go onto the next page.

Comment: @karlkoeller `\makebox[2cm][1]` doesn't work in beamer.

Answer (score 18):

Using a `tabular` as in @PrzemysławScherwentke's answer is a good way to go.

If you still wish to use `itemize`, here are two options, one without bullets and one with bullets.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$E[g(x)] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(x) \, g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$.
%
where,

% Without bullets
\begin{itemize}
    \item[$x$]{is a continuous random variable.}
    \item[$f_X(x)$]{is the PDF of $x$.}
    \item[$g(x)$]{is a function of $x$.}
\end{itemize}

% With bullets
\begin{itemize}
    \item{$x$\hphantom{$g(x)f_X(x)$} is a continuous random variable.}
    \item{$f_X(x)$\hphantom{$xg(x)$} is the PDF of $x$.}
    \item{$g(x)$\hphantom{$xf_X(x)$} is a function of $x$.}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The answer without bullets makes use of the optional argument of `\item`, which just gives the list item a label. The answer with bullets makes use of `\hphantom{}` to ensure that the amount of horizontal space taken up in each line is the same as in the other lines.

Comment: This seems like a great option as it will work for list that span over a page.

Answer (score 16):

I hope that itemize is only a suggestion. A simple solution without it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$E[g(x)] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(x) \, g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$.
%
where

\begin{tabular}{@{$\bullet$ }ll}
   $x$      & is a continuous random variable.\\
   $f_X(x)$ & is the PDF of $x$.\\
   $g(x)$   & is a function of $x$.
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Przemysław. Actually, I am using this within the beamer class. I have a lot of macros customizing my lists. So, I'd rather have it defined in the itemize environment.

Comment: One can also use `\labelitem` instead of directly putting `\bullet`.

Answer (score 10):

To emphasize the connection between the main formula and the three explanatory lines, I'd place them all in an `align*` environment. No real need to clutter up the picture with text bullets.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} % define the expectation operator symbol
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\E[g(x)] &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(x) g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x\\
\shortintertext{where}
x      &\ \text{is a continuous random variable,}\\
f_X(x) &\ \text{is the pdf of $x$, and}\\
g(x)   &\ \text{is a function of $x$.}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

If more space is desired between the variables and the explanatory text, one could replace `&\` with `&\quad`.

---

*Second proposed solution*, incorporating information that this is part of a `beamer` document:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\begin{array}{l@{}l}
\E[g(x)]&{}= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(x) g(x)\, \textnormal{d}x, \text{ where}\\[0.75ex]
x      &\text{is a continuous random variable,}\\
f_X(x) &\text{is the pdf of $x$, and}\\
g(x)   &\text{is a function of $x$.}
\end{array}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Observe that because the main text font is not a "roman"/serif font, it's better to use `\mathnormal` than `\mathrm` to set the "differential operator" symbol `d` in upright shape.

Comment: Thanks, Mico. I am explaining this in a beamer frame and that is why I want it itemized.

Comment: @Ali - I've provided a second solution, which incorporates the information that you're preparing a `beamer` presentation. I still don't think it's necessary to provide "bullet points".