# problems with vertical alignment of large text inside itemize

Tags: equations, itemize, enumitem

I have alignment problems in this type of condition. I set the margin setting for the itemize condition and normally I get a very good result. I would like to get a text aligned for example with respect to V.  I find an example at this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147679/custom-alignment-of-text-in-itemized-environment)

[image]

```
     $\bar{u} = cost$   È la stessa in tutte le realizzazioni;
     $u'$               Varia in ogni prova e rappresenta la parte fluttuante (pulsante,
                        di agitazione) che non contribuisce al trasporto di massa
```

have any suggestions? Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mwe} 

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{-1em}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{5}{4}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{6}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
 primo caso
\begin{itemize}
    \item{\makebox[2cm]{$\bar{u} = cost$\hfill} È la stessa in tutte le realizzazioni;}
    \item{\makebox[2cm]{$u'$\hfill} {Varia in ogni prova e rappresenta la parte fluttuante (pulsante, di agitazione) che non
            contribuisce al trasporto di massa}}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `parbox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mwe} 

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{-1em}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{5}{4}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{6}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
 primo caso
 \begin{itemize}
    \item{\makebox[2cm]{$\bar{u} = cost$\hfill} È la stessa in tutte le realizzazioni;}
    \item{\makebox[2cm]{$u'$\hfill} {Varia in ogni prova e rappresenta la parte fluttuante (pulsante, di agitazione) che non
            contribuisce al trasporto di massa}}
\end{itemize}

non primo caso
\begin{itemize}
    \item{\makebox[2cm]{$\bar{u} = cost$\hfill}} \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm}{È la stessa in tutte le realizzazioni;}
    \item{\makebox[2cm]{$u'$\hfill}} \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm}{Varia in ogni prova e rappresenta la parte fluttuante (pulsante, di agitazione) che non
            contribuisce al trasporto di massa}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

**Explanation of the first argument of my `\parbox` command:** is that I want to use all the available line width (`\linewidth` length), but reduced by `2cm` because these `2cm` have already been used before from the previous `\makebox` command.

Thus the first mandatory argument of the `\parbox` that is used for its width is:

```
\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm
```

Output:

[image]

PS: You could add an optional argument possibly `[t]` like:

```
\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm}{<Your text>}
```

in order to have it aligned to the top of your `\makebox` result.

[image]

Edit: Actually since you already use itemize you can do it using its properties too:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\myitem}[1][]{\item[\textbullet\space\space#1]}

\newenvironment{myitemize}[1][labelwidth=2cm,labelsep=0.4cm,align=parleft,leftmargin =\dimexpr+\labelwidth+\labelsep+\parindent\relax]{\itemize[#1]}{\enditemize}

\begin{document}

 non-non primo caso
 \begin{itemize}[labelwidth=2cm,labelsep=0.4cm,align=parleft,leftmargin =\dimexpr+\labelwidth+\labelsep+\parindent\relax]
    \myitem[$\bar{u} = cost$] È la stessa in tutte le realizzazioni;
    \myitem[$u'$] Varia in ogni prova e rappresenta la parte fluttuante (pulsante, di agitazione) che non
            contribuisce al trasporto di massa
\end{itemize}



non-non primo caso
 \begin{myitemize}
    \myitem[$\bar{u} = cost$] È la stessa in tutte le realizzazioni;
    \myitem[$u'$] Varia in ogni prova e rappresenta la parte fluttuante (pulsante, di agitazione) che non
            contribuisce al trasporto di massa
\end{myitemize}



\end{document}
```

The result is the same and you could use the new environment (`myitemize`) for easier usage.

Comment: great idea, I had overlooked this option. thanks

Comment: @Antonio, check how it can be done easier and with a new environment or without

Answer (score 1):

A solution with the `wide`option and a suitable leftmargin:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{5}{4}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{6}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

 primo caso
\begin{itemize}[wide=\parindent, leftmargin=3cm]
    \item \makebox[2cm][l]{$\bar{u} = \cos t$} È la stessa in tutte le realizzazioni;
    \item \makebox[2cm][l]{$u'$} Varia in ogni prova e rappresenta la parte fluttuante (pulsante, di agitazione) che non
            contribuisce al trasporto di massa
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your help is always illuminating. Thank you