# Captions on the right to math

Tags: captions, itemize, tags

I'm trying to write something like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \(x^2+y^2-1=0; \quad\quad\quad\) (ellipse)
\item \(x^2-y^2-1=0; \quad\quad\quad\) (hyperbola)
\item \(x^2-y=0; \quad\quad\quad\) (parabola)
\end{itemize}
```

I'm struggling to find out how to make it right without using all those \quad and aligning the captions. Thanks in andvance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thank you! Well, it solves the problem but not the way I was thinking about. I wanted the captions to be right-aligned. It isn't a serious problem though - but if it is possible, I'd love to hear how

Answer (score 2):

One option that does not seem to get mentioned in [Custom alignment of text in itemized environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147679/custom-alignment-of-text-in-itemized-environment)
is to use `eqparbox`. It allows you to create boxes of equal width. In more detail all boxes with the same id have the same width. And you can blend this into a macro that allows to further unnecessary repetition. If you use it in another enumerate environment, use a new id.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand\MyItem[2][someid]{\item \eqmakebox[#1][l]{$#2;$}\qquad}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\MyItem{x^2+y^2-1=0} (ellipse)
\MyItem{x^2-y^2-1=0} (hyperbola)
\MyItem{x^2-y=0} (parabola)
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]